# Верно расставлены запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обстоятельственный-оборот

*Причём после выхода картин на экраны успех сопутствовал не только Гафту, но и всем актёрам, задействованным в проекте.*

Нужно ли выделить запятыми ***после выхода картин на экраны***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Причём **после выхода картин на экраны** успех сопутствовал не только Гафту, но и всем актёрам, задействованным в проекте.*

В этом предложении нет необходимости обособления обстоятельственного оборота.
Запятые расставлены верно.

> Во многих случаях... обособление или необособление обстоятельства зависит от степени распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому, стилистической задачи и т. д., поэтому обособление **факультативно.**

См.: [***Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными***](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114) (справочник Розенталя).

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса русского языка:**

*...причем **после неясных странствий** портрет был приобретен музеем города, где художник Леруа родился.* [В. В. Набоков. Посещение музея (1939)]

*Причем **после ночных похождений** наверняка никому не захочется вылезать из машины и открывать ворота.* [Максим Милованов. Естественный отбор (2000)]

*Причем **после нанесения такой пленки** стекло останется по-прежнему прозрачным.* [Наталия Павлова-Каткова // «Известия», 2002.11.11]